# Playing music from parse in swift

Tags: swift, audio, parse-platform

I'm trying to play audio file from [Parse.com](http://parse.com). After running this code I get ***Error occured while getting data!*** printed out. I can't understand why might that be happening. I think URL is correct. When I tried it in browser it started to download music that I'm trying to play. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code or how to solve this problem?

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "AudioFile")
    query.whereKeyExists("audio")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let audio = objects?[0]
            let audioFile = audio?["audio"] as? PFFile
            let filePath = audioFile?.url
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
            let soundData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
            if soundData != nil {
                do {
                    self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData!) // AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
                    self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                    self.audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
                    self.audioPlayer.play()
                } catch {
                    print("Error occured while playing music!")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error occured while getting data!")
            }
        } else {
            print("Error occured while downloading file!")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed code this way.

```
    query.whereKeyExists("audio")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let audio = objects?[0]
            let audioFile = audio?["audio"] as? PFFile
            audioFile?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (audio: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if audio != nil {
                    do {
                        self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audio!)
                        self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                        self.audioPlayer.delegate = self
                        self.audioPlayer.volume = 10.0
                        self.audioPlayer.play()
                    } catch {
                        print("Error occured while playing music!")
                    }
                } else {
                    print ("Somehow audio is nil!")
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("Error occured while downloading file!")
        }
    }
```

Value of 1.0 indicates full volume for the audio player but I was not able to hear it on simulator so I used 10.0. In the first case NSData was nil so I had to change that part of code and used getDataInBackgroundWithBlock. This method is parse method which finds objects asynchronously and calls the given block with the results. In the block NSData isn't nil anymore so AVAudioPlayer works normally.